# Confusion on the proof of Nesbitt Inequalities

Tags: inequality

The attached figure is part of the proof of Quadratic Nesbitt Inequalities, i.e., $\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{c+d}+\dfrac{c}{d+a}+\dfrac{d}{a+b}\ge 2$.

The proof sets:$$
S=\dfrac{a}{b+c}+\dfrac{b}{c+d}+\dfrac{c}{d+a}+\dfrac{d}{a+b};\\M=\dfrac{b}{b+c}+\dfrac{c}{c+d}+\dfrac{d}{d+a}+\dfrac{a}{a+b};\\N=\dfrac{c}{b+c}+\dfrac{d}{c+d}+\dfrac{a}{d+a}+\dfrac{b}{a+b}.
$$
I wonder how the steps are reducted.
[image]

Comment: What are N and S???

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: AM-HM $ \dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y} \ge \dfrac{4}{x+y}$
has been used,

Comment: It's true. But the proof I showed is extracted from a book which has just introduces AM-GM inequality. Since it's a bit irrational to use it without proving, I wonder if there's a way to use AM-GM?

Comment: Note that $(x+y)(1/x+1/y)=1+1+x/y+y/x\ge 2+2=4$ is also AM-GM.

Comment: Well, that's true. Thanks a lot.